# LWUIT 1.4 Plain commands Vs. Styled commands with LWUITTheme.res

Tags: java-me, command, lwuit

I've just started to develope an LWUIT MIDlet with standard LWUITTheme.res. I added 2 commands (Exit, Search) on my first form, but they appear with no style (black on white).

[image: Commands rendere with no style]

Instead, other 2 commands (Back, Details) on a second form, showed on Search command click, are rendered styled in white on blue, with a blue gradient background.

[image: Commands rendere with style]

The first form has a BorderLayout, the second has no particular layout set.

Since I haven't changed commands style in my code, I would expect that their appearance be the same in the first as in the second form, and precisely as they appear in the second form.

Am I wrong?

Regards

--

After @Bhakki first reply, regarding `SoftButton`s, I've checked the `{$LWUIT_FOLDER}/LWUITDemo/src/LWUITTheme.res` file.

[image: Command and SoftButton unselected appearing in LWUITTheme.res]

As you can see, both `Command` and `SoftButton` has in the .res file.
It seems that the commands in the first form are styled as `Command`, and those in the second form are styled as `SoftButton`.

But I added them in the same way in both forms.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I dont understand your question. tell me what is your question here.

Comment: @Bhakki Touché! You're absolutely right. Edited the question, thank you. :) It is clearer now?

Comment: I have tested same way. But its showing properly. Can you post your code?

Comment: @Bhakki You told me: post your code. If I had done it, you would have replied to me 2 days ago. This is the reason for +1 on your comment ;) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created the first form before installing the theme. You need to install the LWUIT theme  before you create components but after Display.init().

Comment: Excellent! :) Exactly as you said... I called `Display.init()` in the costructor of the `MIDlet`, then contructed the first form, then in the `startApp()` method loaded the resources. Now I'm loading resources in the contructor, just **before** constructing the first form, and it works! Thank you very much, Shai! :)